# Is it possible to apply the dynamic data masking on already encrypted column in same table

Tags: encryption, azure-sql-database, data-masking, always-encrypted

I was implemented the Always Encrypted and Dynamic data masking concepts in my azure SQL database on two different tables.

But I have doubt like “Is it possible to apply the dynamic data masking on already encrypted column in same table”.

I tried the above scenario it gives error like “The data type of column 'SSN' does not support data masking function 'partial'.”.

I run the below query for applying the masking on already encrypted column.

```
ALTER TABLE [dbo].[CustomerTables]
ALTER COLUMN [SSN] ADD MASKED WITH (FUNCTION = 'partial(0,"XXX-XX-",4)');
```

Is it possible to apply the dynamic data masking on already encrypted column in same table?

Comment: Do you found a way to mask the data encrypted data in the application?

Comment: No @gotqn, I didn't find anyway to mask the data encrypted.

Comment: There might be a way to do this in the application. To check the certificates access or based on the returned type value. I will examine this and let you know if  I find something.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

No, currently encrypted columns cannot be masked. And, you cannot encrypt a column that has been masked.

With Dynamic Data Masking, masked values are produced on the server side. To produce a masked value (especially using a partial mask), SQL Server needs to know the original value (in plaintext). If a column is encrypted with Always Encrypted, SQL Server only knows ciphertext and it cannot decrypt it - only a client application can decrypt the values stored in encrypted columns.